# How to remove non-English words using RapidMiner

Tags: web-crawler, text-mining, stop-words, rapidminer, web-mining

I am performing text mining in RapidMiner. I am crawling a website and doing some pre-processing tasks like tokenizing, lowercasing and filtering English stopwords; but still I am getting some nonsense words like "xckxzaz", "xkaffqoxzomd" or JavaScript code words like "wpcf". My question is, is there any way in RapidMiner to get rid of these words? I have been told that creating a stopwords dictionary is one solution but that means I'd have to create an entire English dictionary which doesn't look so optimal. Any hint will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Filter Tokens` operator to look for specific nonsense words and set the `Invert Condition` flag. This might be tedious if the list is long since you would need a complex regular expression or multiple operators for the "corpus of nonsense". It would also not be resilient to new nonsense words.

If you know ahead of time what are the English words that you want, you can use a word list input to the `Process Documents` operator. This will eliminate all words that are not in the list but will miss new words that have never been seen but which you might want to keep. You can generate a word list using the output of a `Process Documents` operator.

The `Filter Stopwords (Dictionary)` operator will eliminate stopwords contained in a file so "all you have to do" is create the nonsense corpus.

It depends on what your problem is but I would use the raw word list output saved as a file (use the `WordList to Data` and `Write CSV` operators) which I would edit manually to make a list of nonsense words that I would then use as a dictionary for the stopword filtering.

It's a tricky problem because the essence of the issue is deciding whether a previously unseen work is nonsense or is it English. Is LOL English or nonsense for example?